# TypeScript object property inference from list of keys

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a CSV reader program that takes a list of headers as one property (we'll call this `CsvHeaders`. Another property returns a function whose parameter is an object with keys that are guaranteed to be elmements of `CsvHeaders`. Here's what I've tried:

```js
type CsvHeaders = readonly string[];
type CsvRow = Record<CsvHeaders[number], string>;

interface ICsvReaderProps {
  headers: CsvHeaders;
  onRowClick: (row: CsvRow) => void;
}

const a: ICsvReaderProps = {
  headers: ['A', 'B', 'C'] as const,
  onRowClick: (row) => console.log(row.Anything), // I want this to throw a type error since `Anything` !== `'A' | 'B' | 'C'`.
};
```

`row` in `onRowClick` is inferred as `{ [x: string]: string }`. How can I modify this such that `x` can be inferred as an element of `CsvHeaders`? I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Is it possible that this isn't possible in TS yet? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need `ICsvReaderProps` to be generic in the string literal types of the headers, and you probably want a helper function to infer the generic type argument, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WYRXrw).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Got it -- yes that's perfect! Thank you very much. Feel free to write as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, you need `ICsvReaderProps` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) corresponding to the elements of the `headers` property: let's call that type parameter `T`:

```
interface ICsvReaderProps<T extends string> {
  headers: readonly T[];
  onRowClick: (row: Record<T, string>) => void;
}
```

Then the `row` parameter of the `onRowClick` callback is of type `Record<T, string>` (using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to represent an object type with keys of type `K` and values of type `V`).

So your example object would be of type `ICsvReaderProps<"A" | "B" | "C">`.  In order to avoid the need to manually specify that type parameter (which would make you write `"A"`, `"B"`, and `"C"` twice), we can define a generic identity helper function:

```
const asCsvReaderProps = <T extends string>(x: ICsvReaderProps<T>) => x;
```

And then instead of writing `const a: ICsvReaderProps = {...};` you write `const a = asCsvReaderProps({...});`.  Let's try it:

```
const a = asCsvReaderProps({
  headers: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  onRowClick: (row) => console.log(row.Anything), // error!
  //                          -------> ~~~~~~~~
  // Property 'Anything' does not exist on type 
  // 'Record<"A" | "B" | "C", string>'.
})
```

Looks good.  The compiler infers that `T` is `"A" | "B" | "C"` from the `headers` property, and therefore [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) types `row` in the `onRowClick` callback to be of type `Record<"A" | "B" | "C", string>`.  So `row` is known to have `A`, `B`, and `C` properties of type `string`.  It is not known to have an `Anything` property, so there's a compiler error, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGEDOA3AShOAE2gAUoB7AB0wB4AVZCAD0hEM2UzClAHMA+ZAG8AUMmQALAsSiYAXMijTyIADYBPZHQDaAXQDcY5CtzkA7ulXAEAawUAKCmYX4E5KIXoAaTtz78ASmQAXkFscmBCQwBfETcQLmQ4TCw8aVIKahDkekYWCDYOLh4QAXsmBQwcfCIMqlo6QJDBJkM4lUS4bOTUmpkyevtRcSla2QVtAHIAQUmfSYAhOeRJ9EndLyMTc0trO2RHcyDQ5HjMclUIADpVcl5DsyvpkHUwCT4AnwB6L8YoCigAEIjD9xGDwRDIZCALSwuHQwQAP2RKORIN+A0o0DAmhmLzefEmyEI5AgHBA5DAeWAiRUyBxWOQ6JWrncngARNN2cgAD7IdkLbl89nodk+Yr+SZXETRAJAA)